# configuring FixedWindowRollingPolicy in log4j2

Tags: logging, log4j, log4j2

how to convert following **FixedWindowRollingPolicy** in  log4j 1.x  to xml config using log4j2.

> log4j.appender.events_log=org.apache.log4j.rolling.RollingFileAppender
>   log4j.appender.events_log.rollingPolicy=org.apache.log4j.rolling.FixedWindowRollingPolicy
>   log4j.appender.events_log.rollingPolicy.maxIndex=5

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See the DefaultRolloverStrategy at http://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/manual/appenders.html#DefaultRolloverStrategy. It essentially does the same thing as the FixedWindowRollingPolicy. You would use the FileNamePattern of the RollingFileAppender instead of specifying it on the policy.

```
<RollingFile name="auditfile" fileName="audit.log"
  filePattern="audit.%i.log">
  <PatternLayout pattern="%m%n"/>
  <SizeBasedTriggeringPolicy size="10 MB" />
  <DefaultRolloverStrategy max="5" />
</RollingFile>
```

Comment: Thanks rgoers,it helped me.